# Fixing Dia's Toolbox to the left (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, diagrams

In Windows Dia comes with a toolbox fixed to the left side:

[image]

However in Ubuntu (Gnome) it is floating; is there a way to fix it? Switching all the time between the toolbox and drawing windows is quite annoying.

Comment: The windows version will probably run under wine pretty easily... this is not really an ideal solution though.

Comment: Mh, in my Windows Version (0.97) it's not docked. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to start dia with the --integrated option

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu comes with integrated Dia UI by default. It took me quite a while to discover that the old good floating Dia UI can be started via the command `dia-normal` from the terminal.